# In Laravel 5 cache, between file cache and redis which one is better?

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5 and I don't know which one is better between file and redis cache.

Please give me some recommend.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is in memory and faster. In my opinion it is the best cache option.  You do need to install redis on the server and include predis/predis in your composer file.  In file uses less memory and persists across restarts. You also don't have to install anything for in file.

Comment: If I have only 1G Ram server, should I use redis or file?

Comment: If it is a smaller app you should be able to get away with redis, otherwise you'd probably be better off going in file.   The good news is with laravel it is easy  to switch back and forth if need be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommend.